# Can I run an ML model in sklearn if my variables are contained in arrays

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Currently I have the following dataset:

```
Injury_Type  Organ      PositionGroup    Age          speed
[injured]      [back]         LW           30.929500      5.239167 
[torn]     [biceps]       CB           26.26          4.53
[torn]     [ACL]          LB           26.15          4.44
```

With several more rows like this associating a player with the injury type he sustained, the organ that was injured, the position that they play along with their age and speed. My target is the number of games the player will miss. I am trying to train a model to predict the number of games the player will miss.

Some of the columns are stored in arrays and this is giving me some issues in running my model in sklearn. How can I get around this? I am a beginner to sklearn and if you guys also had any feedback on the process I could use to predict the number of games missed that would be great. I'm trying to build a random forest classfier to first see feature importance after which I will run K-fold validation, scale features and then train the model on a few ML algos.

Do you think this is a good way to go about things? Would you guys suggest any changes?

Comment: Can you please provide a better data sample? ```[back injury, a, back, injury, as, a] ``` is a bad data

Comment: @YusufBaktir thats actually the column for Injury_Type. I had to preprocess my data and extract key phrases and entities with respect to text data and it returns an array with the type of injuries. Other examples include: [shoulder injury, a, shoulder, injury, his],[injuries, back, shoulder, injuries, ailments]. How do you think I could get around this if this is a bad data sample.

Comment: This is a dirty data. You did not do a good job preprocessing it. For example, ```a``` is not an injury, ```as``` is not an injury. You have a larger problem here. The only information that should be is the ```back injury```

Comment: @YusufBaktir I agree, I've actually fixed it now to where it has just ['back'] or ['shoulder'] or [back, calf, shoulder] in the array. Would i then unzip these out of the list and then run the model?

Comment: Can you please update the data? Given that type of data, I may have solid solution for you.

Comment: Hey @YusufBaktir I have edited the data and added a couple of more rows to show you what my data looks like now. I think for the position groups i can use a labelencoder/onehotencoder but not sure if i can do the same thing for the organ or the injury type because there are so many different kinds of injuries and organs. Perhaps it would create too many labels then.

Comment: Ok, this is so much better and workable.

Comment: @YusufBaktir, thanks. What would your solution to this problem be?

Comment: Posted my answer below

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes @YusufBaktir thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CountVectorizer`.
Here you can put multiple items in the array.

for Injury_Type, it can be `['back','leg']`
for Organ, it can also accept multiple inputs.

Count vectorizer will convert each unique item into a dummy variable. From then on, you can use these columns to train a new model.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
data = pd.read_csv('injury.txt',sep=';',converters={'Injury_Type': ast.literal_eval, 'Organ': ast.literal_eval})

data
Injury_Type Organ   PositionGroup   Age speed   daysmissing
0   [back]  [back]  LW  30.9295 5.239167    20
1   [torn]  [biceps]    CB  26.2600 4.530000    10
2   [torn]  [ACL]   LB  26.1500 4.440000    5


data['Injury_Type']
data['Injury_Type_String'] = [' '.join(l) for l in data['Injury_Type']]

data['Organ']
data['Organ_String'] = [' '.join(l) for l in data['Organ']]


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(data['Organ_String']))
Organ_df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
Organ_df
acl back    biceps
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   0

Y = vectorizer.fit_transform(list(data['Injury_Type_String']))
Injury_Type_df = pd.DataFrame(Y.toarray(),columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names())
Injury_Type_df
back    torn
0   1   0
1   0   1
2   0   1


data = pd.concat([data,Organ_df],axis=1)
data = pd.concat([data,Injury_Type_df],axis=1)

del data['Injury_Type']
del data['Injury_Type_String']
del data['Organ']
del data['Organ_String']

print(data)
  PositionGroup      Age     speed  daysmissing  acl  back  biceps  back  torn
0            LW  30.9295  5.239167           20    0     1       0     1     0
1            CB  26.2600  4.530000           10    0     0       1     0     1
2            LB  26.1500  4.440000            5    1     0       0     0     1
```

```
PositionGroup_df = pd.get_dummies(data['PositionGroup'])
data = pd.concat([data,PositionGroup_df],axis=1)

del data['PositionGroup']


print(data)
       Age     speed  daysmissing  acl  back  biceps  back  torn  CB  LB  LW
0  30.9295  5.239167           20    0     1       0     1     0   0   0   1
1  26.2600  4.530000           10    0     0       1     0     1   1   0   0
2  26.1500  4.440000            5    1     0       0     0     1   0   1   0

y = data.pop('daysmissing')
X = data

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regr = RandomForestRegressor()
regr.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not much be said without looking at the data exactly, but I believe, you have some discreet variables which can only take finite set of values e.g., PositionGroup. Training any model would require you to your variables be numbers of continuous variables, hence you would require to represent these variables in some form of numbers to train your model.

I suggest you to first go through the article https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/ so that you can understand the problem better.

Later you may consider using Scikit's `preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()` or `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()`. Do check out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html and go through the given examples. I hope this at least provides you with a way to start. :)

Comment: I am familiar with the encoders and think they would work well for the Position Group but do you know how I could handle the injury type and organ? There would be a lot of different words to encode then?

Comment: Exactly, this is not directly that type of categorical data. Please update the data and I will have a solution for this type of data.

Comment: Could you please tell the possible classes for `injury type` and `organ`?

Comment: @Anant Mittal what do you mean by classes? They're just string with the description of the injury ie: tear, fracture, dislocation and the organ that was affected ie: knee back, shoulder